# Labeled fixtures for associations in Rails 3 broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

After upgrading to Rails 3, fixtures that refer to other labelled fixtures (for relationships) stop working. Instead of finding the actual fixture with that name, the fixture label is interpreted as a string.

Example:

```
# Dog.yml

sparky:
  name: Sparky
  owner: john

# Person.yml

john:
  name: John
```

Where Dog "belongs to" person.

The error message is:

> SQLite3::SQLException: table dogs has no column named 'owner'

Comment: Interesting. I also seem to have the same issue when trying to upgrade my application...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
# Dog.yml

sparky:
  name: Sparky
  owner: john (Person)

# Person.yml

john:
  name: John
```

See the "polymorphic belongs_to" section of http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Fixtures.html

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sparky:
  name: Sparky
  owner: john (Person)
```