# Label associations in Rails fixtures failing with "no columns named..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

I'm trying to use [Label references for associations](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Fixtures.html#label-Label+references+for+associations+(belongs_to%2C+has_one%2C+has_many)) in my simple Rails (6) project but am getting a "no columns named..." error.

Among other things, I have `orders.yml`:

```
one:
  name: Dave Thomas
  address: MyText
  email: dave@example.org
  pay_type: credit_card
```

where `pay_type` is a reference to an entity in `pay_types.yml`:

```
credit_card:
  description: Credit Card
```

However, when I run any tests, I see a fixtures failure:

```
Error:
OrderTest#test_order_attributes_must_not_be_empty:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "orders" has no columns named "pay_type".
    /Users/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:427:in `block in build_fixture_sql'
```

I can make this work by referencing IDs directly, but I'd rather not:

```
pay_type_id: 1
```

`Fixtures.identify` also works as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6748859/328817) (if I rename the file to have a `.yml.erb` extension):

```
pay_type_id: <%= Fixtures.identify(:credit_card) %>
```

but I'd really like to get my original form working.

Here are what the relevant models look like:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :pay_type

  validates :name, :address, :email, presence: true
  validates_presence_of :pay_type
end
```

```
class PayType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order
end
```

and here's an extract from `schema.yml`:

```
  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "address"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "pay_type_id", null: false
    t.index ["pay_type_id"], name: "index_orders_on_pay_type_id"
  end

  create_table "pay_types", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

Things I've tried that haven't helped:

- [Explicitly adding the model type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3232136/328817): `pay_type: credit_card (PayType)`
- [Running `db:test:prepare`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960353/rails-associations-for-fixtures-with-foreign-keys-primary-keys#comment65275444_38960353)

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Update: I imagine it's something I did wrong when switching from a `pay_type` string column to a `pay_type_id` reference on my `Order` model.

If you want to see the full project codebase (it's fairly small): https://github.com/sampart/rails-book-depot/tree/pay-type-label-reference

Context: I'm working through *Agile Web Development with Rails 6* and am doing the extension task  of moving the payment types into the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was my association - [`has_one`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association) assumes a reference on the other side of the relationship, hence looking for a non-existent `order_id` column on `PayType`.

When I changed my `Order` model to have this instead:

```
belongs_to :pay_type
```

then it worked.

Although https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association says "A `belongs_to` association sets up a one-to-one connection with another model", it turns out that they're not *only* for one-to-one relationships.

The key thing is that `belongs_to` expects the foreign key column to be on the model on which the declaration itself is added.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting your solution! I'm going through the same book and was stuck on this exercise too. For me, I had resorted to referencing the ID directly, but then ran into hurdles rendering a `select` dropdown in the order form, and validating the PayType when an order is created.